# Silent undefined variable in view when testing laravel route

Tags: php, laravel, testing, laravel-5, phpunit

I have a `deliverypoint` resource in my laravel project. The controller code associated to the route `deliverypoints.index` is straightforward:

```
public function index()
{
    return view('deliverypoints.index', [
        'deliverypoints' => DeliveryPoint::all(),
    ]);
}
```

With the view `deliverypoints.index`:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
  <ul class="row">
    @foreach ($deliverypoints as $deliverypoint)
      <li class="col-12">{{ $deliveryPoint->id }}</li>
    @endforeach
  </ul>
</div>
@endsection
```

Here you can see a typo in the `li` tag: `deliveryPoint->id` instead of `deliverypoint->id`. This causes an "undefined variable" error when I manually test the route in my browser: so far, so good.

My problem is that when testing the route with PHPUnit, the test passes instead of reporting the error. Here is the code of the feature test:

```
public function testIndex()
{
    $response = $this->get(
        route('deliverypoints.index')
    );

    $response->assertSuccessful()->assertViewIs(
        'deliverypoints.index'
    )->assertViewHasAll(
        ['deliverypoints']
    );
}
```

Since the test passes, I guess the view is successfully returned by the server, but I would expect the typo to be detected.

How can I enforce the test to make it see such errors?

I'm using laravel v5.6 with PHP v7.1.18 and PHPUnit v7.2.6.

**EDIT:**

I tried to clear cache using:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
```

But still the error remains undetected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer: the database wasn't seeded with `DeliveryPoint` instances. So the controller send an empty array to the view through `DeliveryPoint::all` and the loop:

```
@foreach ($deliverypoints as $deliverypoint)
  <li class="col-12">{{ $deliveryPoint->id }}</li>
@endforeach
```

wasn't executed, silenting the error.

A possible fix using factories:

```
public function testIndex()
{
    factory(DeliveryPoint::class)->create(); // seed the database

    $response = $this->get(
        route('deliverypoints.index')
    );

    $response->assertSuccessful()->assertViewIs(
        'deliverypoints.index'
    )->assertViewHasAll(
        ['deliverypoints']
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to add a 200 check before going any further

```
$this->assertEquals(200, $response->status());
```

I have tried to replicate the issue you have and the response is the same in the test than in the browser: 500 response in both cases.

Comment: Thx for your suggestion. The 200 check is performed through `$response->assertSuccessful`. I exchanged my code with yours just in case, but same result: the test passes